# When the user uploads a PDF, I want to display it and when clicked, the PDF should be displayed in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I am trying to do is when a users uploads a file, i create a new html block, add it to the div and i want to display that pdf. When the pdf is clicked i want it to be displayed in a new tab.

```
<label class="btn btn-secondary btn-pills waves-effect waves-themed" for="inputOtherPdfs">Add new PDF</label>
<input type="file" id="inputOtherPdfs" class="form-control-file" style="display:none;" accept="application/pdf" onchange="loadOtherPdf(event, 'otherPdfsDivId')">

        <div class="row" id="otherPdfsDivId">
            </div>

<script>

 function loadOtherPdf(event, id) {
    let html = "<div class='col-3' style='text-align:center' id='div_OtherPdf_" + someId + "'><a href='' target='_blank' name='OtherPdfs'> <img src='../Content /img/pdfLogo.png' style='width: auto; height: 100px; ' />" + event.target.files[0].name + "</a><div style='padding - top: 5px'><button style='width: 60 %; ' type='button' class='btn btn - outline - danger btn - pills waves - effect waves - themed right' >Șterge</button></div>  <br />  </div>";

    $('#' + id).append(html);
    let pdf = document.getElementById('div_OtherPdf_' + fileCount);

    let file = event.target.files[0];
}
<script/>
```

I tried to do put the file in the src of the newly created html:

```
let pdf = document.getElementById('div_OtherPdf_' + fileCount).children[1];
pdf.src = file;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm, not sure how to do that with jQuery.
I'd follow an approach similiar to [Example: Showing thumbnails of user-selected images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images) but injecting the PDF into an iFrame (using a `src` attribute of `data:application/pdf;base64,BASE64-STRING-STARTS-HERE`). You can use the same value as `href` for an `<a>` with `target=_blank` which should allow opening into a new tab.

If that works, make sure to add [additional security measure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) to harden your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the PDF file into an `<object>` instead of the new tab.

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,YOURBASE64DATA" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

create an `<object>` as above and load the `event.target.files[0]` into the **data** attribute.

EDIT: this might not work on some mobile devices, the PDF might not get displayed into the **object** tag.